# Reinitialize transactional replication using powershell

Tags: replication, powershell

Recently I was asked to develop a solution by management to reinitialize a transactional replication whenever it fails using powershell.  The request was made because our 3rd party vendor restores our replicated database as part of their deployment.

I understand there are different versions of SQL servers and Powershell around our server, and develop a script for all versions will be not only hard but also risky.  Also reinitialize will cause the source and destination databases become unusable/locked.  Is anyone aware of this type of powershell solution somewhere?

Comment: https://dbatools.io/functions and Mike Fal are the two things I think when I think Powershell. I couldn't find anything from Mike, that doesn't mean he doesn't have something though. I'm sure someone else here has seen something too.

Comment: Commands around replication are in progress for [dbatools](https://github.com/sqlcollaborative/dbatools/issues/3537)

Comment: Why not be proactive in catching what is causing replication to break instead of going through re-initialization ?